# Suppress default Bootstrap style for printing of some links

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When we try to print certain pages buttons are followed by the href of the link in parentheses. We want the page to print as it looks on the screen.

Here is the html

```
<div>
   <a id="manage-debt-type-btn" class="btn btn-primary" href="Updatype?typeId=98765">
    Update Types
    </a>
</div>
```

What shows up in the print out is a button with

> Update Types Updatetype?typeId=98765

I've tried to add `@media printer { btn-primary...}` but that did nothing.

Comment: we are using bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested, but you can try

```
@media print {
 a[href]:after {
  content: none;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Bootstrap `_print.scss` file inside a `@media print {` media query:

```
a[href]:after {
  content: " (" attr(href) ")";
}

// Don't show links for images, or javascript/internal links
a[href^="javascript:"]:after,
a[href^="#"]:after {
  content: "";
}
```

These default rules can be amended by your CSS. Following the example of their preventing links:

```
a[href]:after {
  content: "";
}
```

or to target which links we suppress:

```
a[href].clean-print:after {
  content: "";
}
```

combined with:

```
<a id="manage-debt-type-btn" class="btn btn-primary clean-print" href="Updatype?typeId=98765">
Update Types
</a>
```